# how to add double quotation character in PHP string using str_replace

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I have String in PHP like:

```
[x,y,z]
```

and I want to change it to

```
["x", "y", "z"]
```

I used str_replace but I can't represent the double quotation mark " in it like this

```
$modified = str_replace("[", "["", $NodeIDs);
```

I also used \ before it like java but it appears in the output. how can I do this?

Comment: use `explode`, `implode` function

Comment: backslash should work: [link](https://3v4l.org/4Ka9A) but you will not achieve result you mentioned that you want..

Comment: Are you sure that `[x,y,z]` is a string and not an array?

Comment: I used explode and implode like below answer

Comment: good, go ahead....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use double quotes `"` inside single quotes `'`:

```
$modified = str_replace("[", '["', $NodeIDs);
```

Or escape them:

```
$modified = str_replace("[", "[\"", $NodeIDs);
```

Or this might be a better approach to get the desired result:

```
$letters = explode(',', trim($NodeIDs, '[]'));
$NodeIDs = '["' . implode('","', $letters) . '"]';
```

Comment: I thought it does not, but it is.

Comment: all works, however I receive in the output / before every ". I am reading the output on android app that receive this echo. the input stream is encoding in iso-8859-1 .. is that the reason?

Comment: Then the \ are being added later, maybe `magic_quotes_gpc` is on or `addslashes()` or `json_encode()`.  Not sure.

Comment: yes, this was the problem. I echoed using json_encode. manythanks

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using `trim`, `explode` and `json_encode`:

```
$output = json_encode(explode(',', trim('[x,y,z]', "[]")));
print_r($output);
//["x","y","z"]
```

---

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/cHQKpT)

Comment: But maybe just trim: `$output = json_encode(explode(',', trim($input, '[]')));`

Comment: @AbraCadaver cleaner, no doubt! tks :)

Answer (score 1):

**Simply do this**

Use `trim` for removing the `[`, `]` from the string, then use `explode` function to get the exploded string and then `implode` them.

```
$str = '[x,y,z]';    
$arr = explode(",", trim($str, "[]"));    
echo $str = '["'.implode('","', $arr).'"]'; //["x","y","z"]
```

Comment: But there must be a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes should do the trick:

```
$modified = str_replace("[", '["', $NodeIDs);
```

Good luck to you on your project!